# LINQ to Entities and polymorphism

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have a simple model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a DbContext:

```
public class MoviesContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have a method in MoviesContext class that filters Movies by substring like this:

```
return Movies.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(filterString)).Select(m => m);
```

Now suppose I'd like to add a new model, say:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + (MiddleName?.Length > 0 ? $" {MiddleName}" : "") + $" {LastName}"; } }
}
```

I also want to filter persons (DbSet Persons) by name (i.e. FullName). I'd like DRY, so it is preferrable to generalize a filter method of MoviesContext. And, what is important, I'd like to do filtering on the database level. So I have to deal with LINQ for Entities.

If not for this, the task is pretty simple. I could use an abstract class and add a virtual method that do the "contains substring" logic. Alternatively, I could use an interface. Unfortunately, because of LINQ for Entities, I can't use a FullName property (which is not convenient but bearable) and I can't write something like this:

```
return dbset.Where(ent => ent.NameContains(filterString)).Select(ent => ent);
```

So, how to solve this problem? I've found some solution (almost have my head broken), but I am not very happy with it. I'll post my solution separately, but I hope there is a more elegant one.

Comment: You can do this with generics, the problem, is that your LINQ query needs to be translated to SQL, and normally it will result in a horrible SQL query to solve this, I would definitively just try native LINQ methods to access my DB

Comment: Using inheritance for this kind of problems immediately breaks Liskow, because most subclasses have nothing in common whatsoever. Inheritance is a *logical* design pattern, not *technical*. This is an important difference. You may get DRY code, but not SOLID.

Comment: Yes, maybe sharing interface is more appropriate, but it looks that in this case its implementing is not trivial also, if possible at all. Maybe even more appropriate to use attributes  - I don't have an experience in this, though, but right now it looks like a possible solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your code a little more closely, instead of your `NameFilterable` abstract class, could you not do something like this:

```
public interface IHasPredicateGetter<T> {
   [NotNull] Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetPredicateFromString([NotNull] string pValue);
}

public class Movie : IHasPredicateGetter<Movie> {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Expression<Func<Movie, bool>> GetPredicateFromString(string pValue) {
      return m => m.Name.Contains(pValue);
   }
}
```

This prevents you from needing a cast, for example. It's so hard to grasp just what you're trying to do here, so I'm not sure this is the whole thing or not. You're still stuck with an instance method that should probably be a static method, but it couldn't implement an interface otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I thought about interface, but failed to implement it because of luck of time/experience. I am going to try your solution, thanks.

Comment: @IgorKrein I think the main thing about this that works is that it's generic inheritance. A generic method runs into the problem where the generic type is seen by the compiler to be the constrained type, and not the actual type. Using generic inheritance, whether it's an interface or class, seems to avoid this problem. (In other words, if you added a type parameter to your `NameFilterable` class, you should be able to do the same thing, making it more strongly typed; though in general it's probably better anyway to use an interface and not a base class.)

Comment: Actually, it looks like the generic inheritance raises new problems. First of all, I can't pass a DbSet<Movie> parameter to MoviesContext.Filter<T>() method which now has the restriction "where T : class, IHasPredicateGetter<T>, new()". And I suspect there will be a problem with classes derived from such as Movie and Person. With my solution (Person : NameFilterable) I could create, say, class Actor: Person, pass DbSet<Actor> to the filter - and all will work. "Generic" way leads to inconsistencies like returning Expression<Func<Person, bool>> value to Expression<Func<Actor, bool>> variable.

Comment: @IgorKrein I can use it just fine hooking it up to my own model. There's no problem passing the DbSet reference, so I'm not sure what you mean. To be honest, your question and requirements are too vague. If you want examples of EF polymorphism, that's one thing. If you want reusable filters, that's another. If you want reusable filters, that even work with inherited types, that's something else. You can't just keep inventing new requirements. Ask a specific question, get a specific answer.

Comment: You're right, it looks like I failed to define all the requirements from the beginning, sorry. Anyway, thank you for sharing your time and knowlege. I'll try to play with your idea a little and ask for help if there is a need.

Comment: Found it! My code didn't compile with DbSet<Actor> while DbSet<Person> indeed was OK. The problem lies in non-covariance of DbSet. Everything works pretty good when I've replaced DbSet<T> with IQueryable<T>. I just have to specify a strict generic (Person for an Actor) when calling Filter method, which is OK.

Answer (score 1):

My solution looks like this.

[1] The base class:

```
public abstract class NameFilterable
{
    protected static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public virtual Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetNameContainsPredicate<T>(string filterString)
    {
        return False<T>();
    }
}
```

[2] The Person class (I'll omit the Movie class, it is more simple):

```
public class Person : NameFilterable
{
    ...
    public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetNameContainsPredicate<T>(string filterString)
    {
        return entity => 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterString) ||
            (entity as Person).LastName.Contains(filterString) ||
            (entity as Person).FirstName.Contains(filterString) ||
            (((entity as Person).MiddleName != null) && (entity as Person).MiddleName.Contains(filterString))
        ;
    }
}
```

[3] The filter methods in MoviesContext:

```
    private static IQueryable<T> _filterDbSet<T>(DbSet<T> set, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterPredicate) where T : class
    {
        return set
            .Where(filterPredicate)
            .Select(ent => ent);
    }

    private static IQueryable<T> _filterDbSet<T>(DbSet<T> set, string search = null) where T : NameFilterable, new()
    {
        T ent = new T();
        return _filterDbSet<T>(set, (ent as NameFilterable).GetNameContainsPredicate<T>(search));
    }

    public static ICollection<T> Filter<T>(DbSet<T> set, string search = null) where T : NameFilterable, new()
    {
        return _filterDbSet(set, search).ToList();
    }
```

And it seems that all this works pretty well. But I can't say it is very elegant.

[1] I have to use a generic T, though on the Person level I always work with Person objects (or descendants). So I have to convert T to Person (as Person).

[2] In GetNameContainsPredicate method, I can't write (because of LINQ for Entities):

```
        return entity => 
        {
            Person p = entity as Person;
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterString) ||
            p.LastName.Contains(filterString) ||
            p.FirstName.Contains(filterString) ||
            ((p.MiddleName != null) && p.MiddleName.Contains(filterString))
        };
```

[3] I can't use static methods (statics couldn't be overridden), so I have to create a dummy T object (T ent = new T();).

[4] I still can't use a FullName.Contains(filterString)

So, the question remains: Maybe I miss something and there is a more elegant solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that is responsible for search if a type has a particular property and filter for that property,if the object has not the property simply return null. Whith this you can create an expression that filters for this property

```
//gets the property info of the property with the giving name
     public static PropertyInfo GetPropetyInfo<T>(string name)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var property = type.GetProperty(name);
            return property;
        }
//Creates an expression thats represents the query
public static Func<T, bool> GetFilterExpression<T>( string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            var prop = GetPropetyInfo<T>(propertyName);
            if(prop==null)return t=>false;
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression expression = parameter;
            var left = Expression.Property(expression, prop);
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var toLower = typeof(string).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals("ToLower"));
                var tlCall = Expression.Call(left, toLower);
                var right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue.ToString().ToLower());
                var contains = Expression.Call(tlCall, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), right);
                var containsCall = Expression.IsTrue(contains);
                expression = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.NotEqual(left, Expression.Constant(null)), containsCall);                
            }
            else
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.ToString().ToLower().Contains("nullable"))
                {
                    var getValue = prop.PropertyType.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals("GetValueOrDefault"));
                    var getValueCall = Expression.Call(left, getValue);
                    var right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
                    expression = Expression.Equal(getValueCall, right);
                }
                else
                {                   
                    var value = Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue,prop.PropertyType);
                    var right = Expression.Constant(value);
                    expression = Expression.Equal(left, right);                  
                }
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }).Compile();
        }
```

The you can use it as follow

```
 var expression = YOURCLASS.GetFilterExpression<Person>("LastName", "Jhon");
var result=dbset.Where(expression);
```

Comment: You have specified the type `Person` to get your expression. You may as well have just written the expression without using reflection: `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> filter = p => p.LastName.Contains("Jhon");`. The trick is to get a filter with a general type, not a concrete one.

Comment: Precisely this is why I use reflection to generate a dynamic filter regardless of type. Entity framework has the mechanism to work dynamically with the types, dbset.Set<T>().

Comment: But what does this do more than just writing the expression normally? Maybe I am missing something. How is it different from or better than `var result = dbset.Where(x => x.LastName == "Jhon");` ?

Comment: If you use the advantages of EF (db.Set <T> ()) you can create your generic repository and dynamically filter the data. It's like making dynamicLINQ , just imagine that is sent from our presentation layer a filter of the following type: property:propertyValue, so from our generic repository would have a filter function (string property, string propertyValue) that dynamically filter the data by a certain property and even by several properties.

Comment: This is one of the advantages that I see, as I think you can find more, depending on your use. In the case of the question, you want to do something like this dbset.Where (ent => ent.NameContains (FilterString)), as I said earlier considering that EF implements generic methods to work with types, from dbset is easy to get the type with which we are working. In the example I put var expression = YOURCLASS.GetFilterExpression <Person> ("LastName", "John"); with Person to be understood what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Hector, but I couldn't compile this yet for some reason. First of all, GetFilterExpression returns Func<T, bool> instead of Expression which is needed for Where. All the changes I've tried so far didn't help. Think, I need some more time to apply your code - it is interesting what SQL code it produces and what its effect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I've done to get polymorphism with EF, but in your specific case of wanting reusable filters, I'm not sure it's worth the trouble. I've basically tried to do the same exact thing, but every time I end up realizing that there's no point. Ask yourself: what exactly are the benefits of doing this, and how is it any more flexible than what a `Where` clause already offers?

There are two issues. One is that it's hard or nigh impossible to get a filter to be used between two separate classes by using a shared interface (`INamedObject` for example). This is because you need a strongly typed expression. You can make a function that returns a strongly typed expression, but why would you not have just wrote the expression in the first place? The other issue is that you need a new filter expression for every search value, which is pretty close to where we are already.

If you perfected this, what would you have? The ability to infer type, specify a search value, and get an expression you could use? Isn't that essentially what we already have? The way `Where` clauses already are, they already have strong typing, *and* the ability to use dynamic search values. While it might feel a tiny bit redundant to say `x => x.Name == value` in more than one place, really the ability to specify such a concise and powerful filter statement is already a pretty amazing place to be.

Comment: As I said, I'd like to "not repeat myself", that's all basically. Right now there are 3 filter methods (look at my own answer): a low-level one that do ANY type of filtering (I could pass to it predicate that filters, say, ID field by array of values); a middle-level one that uses specific filter: and a high-level method that converts result set to a list. Now, if I want to add another filter, I should add 2 more methods (mid&high). And if I want to go async, I should add an async version for each high-level method. This is already pretty much. I don't like to do the same for every each model.

Comment: @IgorKrein My point is that I don't think this is a good time to use DRY. The benefit here is an illusion. You are not getting anything of value by saying `.Where(nameIsJoeFilter)` rather than `.Where(x => x.Name == "Joe")`. If you want to cache a particular filter to reuse it rather than type it five times at once, you already can with `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> nameIsJoeFilter = x => x.Name == "Joe";`. And you could make an expression generator as well. Maybe that is what you're looking for; I will append to my answer.

Comment: @IgorKrein Well, there are issues with writing a generic expression generator. Even though it should be strongly typed to T, it still insists on treating T as the type of its constraint. This can only be worked around by "manually" constructing the expression. But this would only give you a strongly typed expression generator; only the generator would be reusable (make me a filter for Persons with search word "Fred", make me another filter for Movies with search word "Fred", etc.). You simply cannot use a more general type L2E expression, since L2E relies on reading the expression tree.

Comment: @IgorKrein maybe what you really want is a replacement for `Where`. You will still encounter the generic type problem. I've appended an example.

Comment: @IgorKrein going to write a separate answer for my attempt at a solution

Comment: Sorry for not responding more often - it looks like we are on the opposite points of Earth, so the conversation is far from dynamic. But, as I replied to your separate answer, the interface looks like a good idea and I am going to try it when there is a time. Expression generator - no, I don't want it right now, this is too complex. Actually, all I need is to implement a logic for ID+Name pairs that could be used in many cases like drop-down boxes, for example.

Comment: @IgorKrein "all I need is to implement a logic for ID+Name pairs that could be used in many cases like drop-down boxes, for example." That's funny because my original answer was going to be posting a few of the tricks I've used to do that kind of thing. Maybe I'll post another answer with that. I might delete this one later.